# Azure SQL Built-in Backup not completing

Tags: azure-sql

I've configured the retention policy in 'Manage Backups' for my Azure SQL Server but nothing is appearing under 'Available Backups'. Does there need to be an associated storage account? If so, how do I set it up?

Previously, I thought it was possible to configure where the backups were stored. I may have accidentally deleted the storage account or container that was being used but there seems to be no way to set it up again.